# UIWebView is very slow

Tags: ios

I'm building a custom RSS reader app with incorporated feed link view (UIWebView).

Using the following code, when the view, containing WebUIView is loaded, it takes about 6 seconds before anything is outputted to the user:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 NSString *urlString = [[[self appDelegate] currentlySelectedBlogItem]linkUrl]; 
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 [_webview loadRequest:requestObj];
 [_webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
 }
```

Any ideas why UIWebView is being so slow?

I've checked the URL input, it's clean and what I'd expect it to be. I'm building for iOS 3.0 as base deployment target.

Comment: Adding a process indicator may enhance the UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the built-in browser from UIWebView is not optimized like MobileSafari.

Comment: Correct. It does not include the JIT compiler for security reasons.

Comment: It doesn't include Nitro JS engine as Safari, so it's slower executing JS.

Answer (score 2):

This has help me:

```
[webView setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeNone];
```

But the statment about jit for JS on WebView is also correct - mobile safari is faster.

Comment: What are the consequences of setting this value?